# ProcessMaker - need supervisors to have access to each other's completed cases

Tags: triggers, permissions, assign, processmaker

I have a process in 3.0.1 community where users are filling out forms with input documents that are then routed to an unassigned inbox for supervisors. While the cases are active, the supervisors have access to see each other's cases. However, when the case is completed it is only accessible to the supervisor that completed the case.

I need to know if there's a way to keep the case visible after completion without using the advanced search option.

I tried passing the case to the other supervisor before the case completes, but it didn't work.

```
$username   = 'admin'; 
$query_user = executeQuery("SELECT FROM USERS where USR_USERNAME='$username'"); 
$user_uid    = $query_user[1]['USR_UID']; 
@@SYS_NEXT_USER_TO_BE_ASSIGNED = $user_uid;
```

I also tried running a parallel process and having it automatically close, but it creates a mess with the case numbers. The user also has to go in and open the case just to close it.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or ideas where to look for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are idea wherein we can do that:

1.) Using the participation tab, if you participated in the case I think you can see it in that tab, if not use #2.

2.) Create a project that have only 1 task and add a dynaform with a data-table on it(http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/Panel_Control), query all cases that is under that project you want to see so that you need not to search them via advance search that is draining so much resources.

3.) PM-Table by adding a trigger after the case completed to write the details in a certain PM Table for your review.

4.) Reporting tool ( if available), just set it up and you can easily find all cases completed. automatically.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The supervisors need access to all cases completed by other supervisors as well. Participated only works for the cases they worked on.

Comment: Number 2 is interesting, I might try that later. I found a way to force advanced search to filter based on the user. It just took a quick modification to the source code.

Comment: That is awesome but on enterprise, they prohibit modifying the source code.